# Can no longer type quotation marks in IDLE3.5. Pycharm (2018.3) and Netbeans, why?

Tags: pycharm, python-3.5, python-idle

I am struggling with a weird situation.
For a week or so quotation marks (', " but also ^) no longer appear when I type them in IDLE 3.5 (I get ¨ and ´ instead), Pycharm or Netbeans ( in the latter 2 I get just a space instead).

I run Linux Mint Mate 18.3 with a workman keyboard layout. In all other applications (Gedit, Vim, Eclipse, Anaconda, LibreOffice, terminal, Firefox, Chrome,...) nothing has changed and everything works just fine. The problem dates from before the last update I ran a couple of days ago (in the hope it would solve the problem) and no new hard- or software was added to my system.

Anyone out there any idea why this is happening and why it only seems to affect these 3 programs? Or suggestions on how to solve it?

So far changing keyboard layout, removing and reinstalling the affected software have not made a difference. I also have not found any other information related to this issue, which I find strange.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Something like this recently happened to me when cat in my lap pawed the keyboard and changed the Windows Input Method from English to Spanish.  I did not check if everything is affected. ...  IDLE uses tkinter, which wraps tcl/tk.  Tk gets key events from the OS and if they represent characters, inserts them in a Text widget.  IDLE monitors the flow of characters for syntax coloring, but does not make replacements.

Comment: @Terry Thank you. I think you are on the right track. I use fcitx to input Chinese from time to time. Most likely that causes the problem but because the key bindings in those programs overlap with those of fcitx I don't seem able to set my keyboard to the english input. I will look into it some more.

Comment: So the 3 apps with problems are editors with multiple keybindings that could conflict with your background keyboard program.  At least for IDLE, you might be able to create a custom set of keybindings that avoid conflict.  If you find fcitx's 'change language' binding, you could look at the Keyset tab of the settings dialog.